# GPFlow model gives bad predictions on test set

Tags: python, tensorflow, predict, gpflow, gaussian-process

Good day!

I was using GPFlow regression to model function on a sphere (spherical distance between point and North Pole). Here is my code:

```
model = gpflow.models.GPR(data=(nodes_train, fs_train), kernel=kernel, noise_variance=0.01)

gpflow.utilities.set_trainable(model.likelihood.variance, False)
model.likelihood.variance.assign(0.0001)

optimize_GPR(model, 500)
```

I've chosen train&test set randomly on the sphere using

`train_test_split(data, test_size = 0.33)`

I set one parameter not trainable, because my model gave bad prediction on both test & train sets. Now I have very bad predictions (using `predict_f()`) on test set and very good predictions on train set, also on test set it looks like model gives arbitrary distributed values with *large* covariance of predictions. Here is a visualisation (I postpone the value of the function from the corresponding point on a sphere)

**Question**: How can I fix predictions on a test set? What could be the problem?

***Images***:

| Predictions on train set | Predictions on test set |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |